# Why I get Error message when i run 'npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles' command

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a web page, but it`s has some warning issue like this:

> "Warning: componentWillUpdate has been renamed".

I run `"npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles"` this command then it give me a error look like this. 
[image]

Comment: What is your react version?

Comment: react version : 16.9.0

Comment: Can you give the full error? It looks like there's an error stacktrace that is cutoff in your screenshot?

Comment: look at your code, what changed in componentWillUpdate? componentWillUpdate can be problem to lifecycles